# Can't reduce size of resizable textarea in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a textarea:

```
<textarea cols="1" rows="1" style="width:500px; height:200px;"></textarea>
```

For some reason I can't make it smaller when resizing with mouse cursor in Chrome though in Fifefox it works fine. What have I missed?

Comment: Is the text-area resizing behaviour normalized ? I don't think it's really simply html.

Comment: I don't believe so because in IE9 i don't get the option to resize text areas.  Chrome will obey the minimum / maximums for boxes whereas FF does not.

Answer (score 4):

You've done nothing wrong, your code is correct, but you've encountered a bug in Chrome:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94583

It treats your css height value as a min-height value, a bug that's been around for at least 2 years

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<textarea cols="1" rows="1" style="width:auto; min-width:300px; height:200px; resize:both;"></textarea>
```

I think in chrome we cant reduce width if its set.

Comment: Firefox's is the more useful behavior. The `textarea` starts out sized as styled, but then the user can resized it up _or_ down by dragging the resize handle.

Comment: The correct part of the answer is “in chrome we cant reduce width if its set”, or more exactly that Chrome does not let either dimension to be decreased from what they have been set in HTML or in CSS.