# Can't reduce size of textarea in Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, textarea, opera

I can't reduce size of textarea using mouse although I didn't specify minimum width and height. In Firefox everything is ok. This question was asked here: [Can't reduce size of resizable textarea in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356797/cant-reduce-size-of-resizable-textarea-in-chrome),  but I couldn't find suitable answer, maybe someone can help me.

This is my mark up:

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>
```

and CSS:

```
textarea{
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px dashed black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: Purisa;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 20px auto auto auto;
    outline: none;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: When your question has already been asked, you should not post a duplicate but try to have the answers to an existing question improved. We do no want to have copies of the same question, with different sets of answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't reduce size of resizable textarea in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356797/cant-reduce-size-of-resizable-textarea-in-chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome has a some kind of **restriction** to show content properly to user. Because of that they edited the default actions of **resizing** on `<textarea>`. In older versions of chrome there was no restriction.

So if you use `height` `min-height` will be your height. So you need to set `min-height` and `max-height` only. `Height` overrides min-height in Chrome.

Here is a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gAr72/1/

*Edit:*

You can see **Firefox** will work same as **Chrome** in this fiddle. Height is risky for design btw. Unlimited resizing always breaks the design. So limiting height and width is good option.