# How can I specify a preferred width/height for a text area, but allowing the user to make larger or smaller?

Tags: css

I have a textarea (in Chrome) defined as:

```
<textarea style="width:100%; height:500px;"></textarea>
```

This forces the text area to have those dimensions, which are the preferred dimensions, so that's good.

However if the user wants to drag the resize handle to make that textarea smaller or larger, they can't

If I remove the style all together, then the text area collapses to a small square.

I want to specify the preferred size, but let the user drag it larger or smaller in any direction. Can this be done?

Comment: Generally resize seems to work for increasing size, but not so well for decreasing the size.

Comment: Just a note:  In Firefox resizing is allowed by default even with fixed width/height CSS settings. If you set min-width/min-height, user can increase size in Chrome... It solves problem partially.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356797/cant-reduce-size-of-resizable-textarea-in-chrome, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178301/how-can-i-use-css-resize-to-resize-an-element-to-a-height-width-less-than-init, etc.

Comment: It may also be worth considering going the route of "auto-resizing" based on the amount of content/text within the textarea see: http://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/kefknbyr/ Cool right?

Comment: @LGSon yes, I agree

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify dimensions using the attributes `rows` and `cols`, e.g.

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
```

`rows` = the number of lines high the textarea should be.

`cols` = the number of characters wide the textarea should be.

Depending on the rest of your css, the textarea may not go wider than its parent container.

Comment: How does this address resizability?

Comment: This still doesn't let me resize below the specified dimensions, at least not in Chrome

Comment: This doesn't solve the _make that textarea smaller or larger_